# How to search through a database table using two columns

Tags: python, sql, pyqt5

I want to use two columns in my database table as search parameters namely First Name and Last Name.So when the user press a letter in a search field(lineEdit) the search will return all the words having the letter pressed by the to be displayed in a QTableView or a QTableWidget.I could only do this search using just a column. Please I need help on how to implement this or is there a better way of doing this using just sql statement, below is what I have done. Thank you in advance.

```
search_method = ''' SELECT id_no,firstname,surname FROM name_list'''

sql_search_method = cur.execute(search_method).fetchall()
        
model = QStandardItemModel(len(sql_search_method), 1)
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Id_no','First Name','Surname'])

for row, company in enumerate(sql_search_method):

    for com_name in company:
        item = QStandardItem(com_name)
        model.setItem(row, 1, item)

filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(1)


self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)

self.ui.tableView.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12px;')
self.ui.tableView.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.ui.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.ui.tableView.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
```

Comment: Use a [QSqlQueryModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) so you can do all the filtering in the select statement.

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't know QSqlQueryModel, I'm using sqlite. Please can it this task be achieved with sqlite?

Comment: Why don't you just learn how to use it? It's not at all difficult. All you need to do is reset the query when the text changes, and the model will do the rest.